# Can you use a private match to fulfill mission objectives?

Tags: the-last-of-us, the-last-of-us-remastered

The missions with the various Attacks. Can you go into a private match with your buddies, like interrogation where you have infinite lives, and just let each other kill the other to fulfill the mission objective?

Answer (score 1):

No you can not, sadly. The mission you do to keep your clan alive or to increase the population only counts towards your games played in multiplayer public matches and any downs, executions, revives and heals etc... Are not counted as a part of your mission or even to the online leaderboards.